# how to count unread status notification include another table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two table

[tblnotificationstatuses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlFZh.png)

[tblnotifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpdeT.png)

```
SELECT count(a.notificationId) as countUnread FROM tblnotifications as a  LEFT JOIN tblnotificationstatuses as b on a.notificationId=b.notificationIdWHERE b.userId='916eb7e2-ee73-448f-9de0-024fe4de7aff' and b.status=0 OR a.notificationType=1
```

expect result unread count is 3 (one direct notification & two blast notification)

if i update  tblnotificationstatuses status = 1 result  count  still 3

my expect result is 2 ( just count the blast notif only )

tblnotifications.notificationId wil not exist in tblnotificationstatuses .notificationId until this notif read by userId

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(unread) as unreadTotal 
    FROM (
    SELECT count(notificationId) as unread FROM tblnotifications as n WHERE  n.notificationType=1 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM tblnotificationstatuses as ns
        WHERE n.notificationId = ns.notificationId
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(userId) as unread FROM tblnotificationstatuses as c WHERE userId='916eb7e2-ee73-448f-9de0-024fe4de7aff' AND c.status=0 AND EXISTS ( SELECT NOT NULL FROM tblnotificationstatuses as d WHERE c.notificationId = d.notificationId )
    ) d;
```